# Matlab regarding assigning graphs in overlayers and reuse

Tags: matlab

I have started learning matlab a month ago. I want to create graphs with multiple iteration (this I can do) and sum up (add together) the individual graphs and get a resultant graph (this I could not do) in the same window. My question is how can I assign each graph in the over layer (obtained by multiple iteration) and so that I can reuse that for latter purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you'd like to superimpose all of the individual graphs in one figure? If so, the [hold](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) command can likely solve your problem. Example below:

```
t = 1:.1:10;

y1 = sin(t);
y2 = sin(2*t);
y3 = sin(3*t);

plot(t, y1)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('y(t)')

hold all    % this causes new plots to appear in the same figure
plot(t, y2, 'r-')
plot(t, y3, 'g-')

fig = gcf;                    % gets the current figure
saveas(fig, 'myFileName.fig') % saves a "figure" object that matlab can open
saveas(fig, 'myFileName.png') % saves a .png image
```

If not, please clarify and I'll be glad to try to you help further.